# How to append a string into an object 'path' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this path in a string: `var path = 'bonds.international.emergent'` and the object `portfolio`.

I want to access `portfolio.bonds.international.emergent`, using the path in the `path` variable.

Something like `portfolio[path]`, which obviously doesn't work. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's only dots, you can split:

```
var path = 'bonds.international.emergent';
var target = portfolio;
path = path.split('.');
for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
  target = target[path[i]];
}
alert(target); // = portfolio.bonds.international.emergent
```

Else, you can eval:

```
var target = eval('portfolio.' + path);
```

But avoid eval if you can.